# docker-compose not finding entrypoint dll but running the dockerfile works

Tags: .net, linux, docker, docker-compose

So i'm trying to put all our different projects in dotnet in containers using one single docker-compose. I have managed to run one of the projects using the built in docker integration in Visual Studio.

The dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

# Copy the source code into the container
COPY . .

# Set the working directory for the build
WORKDIR /src/Activities

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Development

# Perform the publish into a specific output directory
RUN dotnet publish -c Debug -o /app "./Activities.csproj"

# Use the runtime image as the base image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:7.0 AS base

WORKDIR /app

# Copy the published output from the build stage into the final stage
COPY --from=build /app .

# Specify the entrypoint for the container
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Activities.dll"]
```

And is located in the folder root/Activities.
That works fine. But then i want to run it using my docker-compose.yml file which is located in the root folder.

The docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3.9'

services:           
  redis:
    image: redis
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports: 
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - mynetwork
      
  activities:
    build:
      context: ./Activities
      dockerfile: ./Activities/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /app:/app
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    depends_on:
      - redis      

networks:
    mynetwork:
        driver: bridge
```

But when i run docker-compose up it can't find the Activities.dll

```
 The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
   * You intended to execute a .NET application:
       The application 'Activities.dll' does not exist.
   * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
       No .NET SDKs were found.

 Download a .NET SDK:
 https://aka.ms/dotnet/download

 Learn about SDK resolution:
 https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found
```

I have tried changing the context of which the docker-compose should run the activities project but that doesn't work. I have also tried different ways of copying the files in the dockerfile. But since VisualStudio can run the project just fine i feel like the compose file is just using the wrong context?

Comment: Is your docker engine up to date ? I had a strange behavior not so long ago with docker compose building an image in a subdirectory (involving file not found at runtime, I don't remember all details), so it seems quite similar. When I built the image manually (not with compose) it was fine. After updating docker, everything get back to work, even by building with docker compose.

Comment: The `volumes:` block hides everything in the `/app` directory of your image, including the built DLL.  You can safely delete that to run the code that's actually built into the image.